# How to distinguish between a selected and important menu item?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, navigation, interface, menu

If you wanted a user to distinguish if a menu item is important and not selected.

How will you represent the difference between the selected and the important menu item?

The only idea I would come up with is to add a small lock symbol to the menu item.

Comment: A lock symbol on a menu item usually denotes that the page requires authentication, or isn't available to the user. Unless that is the case with your item, you should consider other symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here some examples:

### Icons

[mediamarkt.de](https://www.mediamarkt.de/)

[image: mediamarkt]

---

### Color

[levi.com](https://www.levi.com/GB/en_GB/)

[image: levi]

---

### Typographic style

[adidas.co.uk](https://www.adidas.co.uk/)

[image: adidas]

---

### Relevant info

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)

[image]

---

### Product Logo

[hebo.com](https://hebo.com/gb/)

[image: hebo]

---

### Mascot

[seek.com](https://www.seek.com.au/)

[image: seek]

---

### Figure/ground

[publitas.com](https://www.publitas.com/)

[image: publitas]

---

### Tagline

[esky.co.uk](https://www.esky.co.uk/)

[image: esky]

---

Comment: I like the exclamation mark

Comment: I have problems to find the animated one, but I'm sure I saw it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is to indicate the important menu item with a background color. Use a similar shade of the background color for a hover effect. On mobile, you could do the same thing but use a touch event instead of hover.

Another option is to use a very benign/unobtrusive css animation to dictate the important menu item.

I personally wouldn't use icons.

Comment: The problem with another BG colour is, that this can be misunderstood as "active"

Comment: You are correct. Allow me to clarify the aforementioned with a mockup:
https://codepen.io/eastcoastdeveloper/pen/rNGZewz

Comment: A mock-up is a good way to show. But still, there too: is is not clear which is active and which is promoted